# How does the CRC-32 algorithm work?

Tags: algorithm, crc

After doing some research on the CRC-32 algorithm, I got to the following:

```
/* Usage: Recursively call this with previous crc. Start with crc = 0. */
#define POLYNOMIAL 0x04C11DB7

unsigned int crc32( unsigned int crc, char* msg, unsigned int len ) {
  for ( unsigned int byteNum = 0; byteNum < len; byteNum++ ) {
    char msgByte = msg[ byteNum ];

    for ( unsigned int bitNum = 0; bitNum < 8; bitNum++ ) {
      char msgBit = ( msgByte >> ( 7 - bitNum ) ) & 0x1;

      if ( ( crc & 0x80000000 ) != 0 )
        crc = ( ( crc << 1 ) | msgBit ) ^ POLYNOMIAL;
      else
        crc = ( crc << 1 ) | msgBit;
    }
  }
  return crc;
}
```

However the output of my code is totally different from those of commonly used CRC-32 functions ( Optimized with tables )

Now I hoped someone could give me example source code for the CRC-32 algorithm, which is not optimized by tables, and gives good insight in how it actually works.

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: CRC is a framework. You can inject different sub-formulas into it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Mathematics_of_CRC They also tell ZLib uses Adler-32 which is not exactly CRC  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32

Comment: Solved. I stumbled by coincidence on the following url: http://stigge.org/martin/pub/SAR-PR-2006-05.pdf
Page 18 contains my solution. For some strange reason I shifted to the wrong side, and the polynomial should be reversed.  
Anyway, Everyone many thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't add 'solved' to your title - add an answer to your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

The CRC-32 algorithm considers the input as a big poynomial in base 2. Each input bit is the coefficient of one power of x. For example, the last bit is the coefficient of x^0, the last but one bit is the coefficient of x^1 and so on.

This polynomial is divided by the generator polynomial, which has degree 32 (i.e. the highest power is x^32). All calculations are performed in the ring of polynomials over the field GF(2). There are different generator polynomials in use, so there is not really only one CRC-32 algorithm. They also differ in other respects (for example bit order).

The CRC-32 value is the remainder of this polynomial division, a polynomial of at most degree 31, which is again represented by the bits of its coefficients.

Comment: I thought my snippet contains the polynomial division. 0x04C11DB7 is the polynomial. It gets XOR'ed if the top-bit of the crc is 1. Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: It is not really clear, where you get the top bit from. It should be the bit that is shifted out at the left when you do `( crc << 1 ) | next-msg-bit`

Comment: I edited the pseudo to my current C code. I hope it clears it up

Comment: Yes, it is correct now. As I mentioned there are other differences between the algorithms. Some use the bits in reversed order, some flip the bytes of the result, some invert the result, ...

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look right:

```
if ( ( crc & 0x80000000 ) != 0 )
    crc ^= POLYNOMIAL;
crc = ( crc << 1 ) | msgBit;
```

You need to test the `crc` high bit before shifting, but xor the rest of the POLYNOMIAL **after** shifting and inserting the message bit.

Note that the actual polynomial is `0x104C11DB7`, and that the 1 in bit 32 cancels `0x80000000 << 1` (which the test proved is set)

Comment: ...or you can insert the message bit last, but only if you inject it using `^` instead of `|`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Yes, xor is commutative.

Comment: I edited the code to change the order.
Unfortunately it still doesn't give the required output.

The 32 bit in the polynomial is unnecessary, because I'm working with 32-bit integers. There is no 32th bit in a 32-bit integer. ( It gets shifted out )

Comment: @Dennis: The polynomial requires 33 bits to store.  32-bit integers are usable only with the "trick" of saving the high bit of the accumulator prior to the shift, and making the high bit of the polynomial implicit.

Comment: @Dennis: I don't see the initialization or final xor, those might explain your mismatch.

Comment: I already tried initializing with 0xFFFFFFFF, and xor with it at the end. Unfortunately that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The one used in archivers etc looks like this:

```
char msg[] = "hello, world!";
uint POLY = 0xEDB88320;

int main( void ) {
  uint i,j,l,x;
  l = sizeof(msg)-1;
  x = 0;
  for( i=0; i<l; i++ ) {
     x = x ^ msg[i];
     for( j=0; j<8; j++ ) {
       x = (x>>1) ^ 0x80000000 ^ ((~x&1)*POLY);
     }
  }
  printf( "crc32(\"%s\")=%08X\n", msg, x );
}
```

http://rextester.com/EHM45452

Or alternatively

```
x = 0;
for( i=0; i<l; i++ ) {
   x = x ^ (msg[i]^0xFF);
   for( j=0; j<8; j++ ) {
     x = (x>>1) ^ ((x&1)*POLY);
   }
   x ^= 0xFF000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled by coincidence on the following pdf: [stigge.org/martin/pub/SAR-PR-2006-05.pdf](http://stigge.org/martin/pub/SAR-PR-2006-05.pdf)
Page 18 contains my solution.

For some strange reason I shifted to the wrong side, and the polynomial should be reversed.

This is the code which gives me the correct output:

```
/* Usage: Recursively call this with previous crc. Start with crc = 0. */

#define POLYNOMIAL 0xEDB88320

unsigned int crc32( unsigned int crc, char* msg, unsigned int len ) {
  crc ^= 0xFFFFFFFF;
  for ( unsigned int byteNum = 0; byteNum < len; byteNum++ ) {
    char msgByte = msg[ byteNum ];

    for ( unsigned int bitNum = 0; bitNum < 8; bitNum++ ) {
      if ( ( crc ^ msgByte ) & 1 )
        crc = ( crc >> 1 ) ^ POLYNOMIAL;
      else
        crc >>= 1;
      msgByte >>= 1;
    }
  }
  return crc ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```